# Using repos vs compile: hot wo replace Nginx from repo with a compiled Nginx?

Tags: package-management, ppa, compiling, nginx

Sometime ago I used [Kura's PPA](https://kura.io/2013/07/10/nginx-spdy-and-ngx-pagespeed/) to install Nginx+Pagespeed on my VPS. I would like to update it to the newest version, but the latest packages from Kura aren't so recent and I'm thinking about downloading them by myself (Nginx + Pagespeed), compiling them and using them instead of the ones provided by the PPA.

I wonder what is the right process to do this. Do I have to remove the Kura packages and then compile and install the latest, official ones, or can I just compile and install those ones and they will substitute the PPA packages?

Comment: did you in the meanwhile solve this problem on your own?

Comment: Sorry. I finally compiled it from scratch on a new VPS, but your solution seems pretty good. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, re-compiling the source is as easy as outlined in this [code snippet on github](https://gist.github.com/tollmanz/8662688), which mainly is making sure that the paths are correct for Ubuntu.

Here is a short overview on which paths are important for ubuntu:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
--user=www-data \
--group=www-data \
```

also, as outlined in this similar question on SO ([How to replace package install of nginx with compiled from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584701/how-to-replace-package-install-of-nginx-with-compiled-from-source)) is is described, that apt-get autoremove nginx (or whatever version you have installed) will still keep the configuration-files, which you can re-use with the freshly compiled version later on.

After just testing it myself on Ubuntu 14.04, i can confirm that these steps are perfectly working, with a downtime of only a few seconds:

1. run the [compile-nginx.sh script from this github gist](https://gist.github.com/parasew/099341f8f84abc7a55f4) and let a package with the latest stable nginx (1.8.0) be created.
2. uninstall the nginx packages from your system

   > apt-get autoremove nginx nginx-common nginx-custom
3. install the new package

   > dpkg -i dpkg -i /home//sources/nginx-1.8.0/nginx_1.8.0-1_amd64.deb
4. restart nginx

   > sudo service nginx restart

At this stage, the old nginx processes should be still in RAM, so the service should refuse to start (port already taken). So you can make sure that everything else is correct (I had to create the directory /var/cache/nginx/client_temp ) - if everything is alright do

```
> sudo killall nginx
> sudo service nginx restart
```

5. there is no step 5, your sites should be up and running again :)