# How to replace package install of nginx with compiled from source?

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx a while ago using the ubuntu PPA repository.  Now I want to compile nginx from source so I can compile in and use the geo-ip module.

I know how to compile the new nginx from source.

How can I remove the nginx binary which was installed by the package?  I want to leave all the configs and logs and upstart stuff etc untouched.  I really just want to remove the old binary.

How can I do this?

Comment: The version of nginx in the main Ubuntu repos (can't speak for PPAs) is compiled with the geo-ip module. See the [build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/185112640/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-amd64.nginx_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1_UPLOADING.txt.gz) for Ubuntu Trusty's nginx.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know nginx was in the main Ubuntu repos; I was following the [instructions on the nginx website](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html).

Comment: I should mention that the version of nginx in Ubuntu Trusty is 1.4.6, while Utopic has version 1.6.2, so if you aren't using any bleeding-edge feature, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify the `--purge` option (or use the `purge` command), the configuration files are left untouched while uninstallation. Therefore all you need to do is:

```
apt-get autoremove nginx
```

Or, if you installed a specific variant (such as `-core`, `-full`, `-extra`, etc.):

```
apt-get autoremove nginx-core
```